# How to solve Phonegap desktop plugins cordova.plugins.diagnostic is undefined error?

Tags: cordova-plugins, phonegap-desktop-app

I'm using Phonegap desktop 0.4.5 to create new Phonegap project with framework 7 (provided by Phonegap desktop 0.4.5).

I have followed the instruction and added 
 into my config.xml file in my project.

When I run the project in my iPhone iOS 10.3.3, I notice that phonegap desktop downloaded the plugin successfully, but in my iPhone, it said `cordova.plugins.diagnostic is undefined`.

I don't know what went wrong.
Can someone give me any ideas ?
Thanks you.